# Unable to authenticate google drive api using python

Tags: python, api, google-drive-api

I have downloaded the `client_secrets.json` file and I am using this redirect_uri: `http://localhost:8080/`.

**This is the code:**

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

**This is the error:**

```
"C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/thisi/Downloads/Bot Tales/Python Script/venv/bot tales scripts/google drive access"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 386, in LoadClientConfigFile
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(client_config_file)
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 126, in _loadfile
    return _validate_clientsecrets(obj)
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 99, in _validate_clientsecrets
    raise InvalidClientSecretsError(
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "client_secret" in a client type of "web".

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\bot tales scripts\google drive access", line 4, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 113, in _decorated
    self.GetFlow()
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 443, in GetFlow
    self.LoadClientConfig()
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 366, in LoadClientConfig
    self.LoadClientConfigFile()
  File "C:\Users\thisi\Downloads\Bot Tales\Python Script\venv\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 388, in LoadClientConfigFile
    raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
pydrive.settings.InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file Missing property "client_secret" in a client type of "web".

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Before the above error was not happening I was getting redirect_uri mismatch error in google authentication window, but now I am not getting even there.

Comment: Seems your secrets file is missing the `client_secret` key

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have created the wrong type of credentials.   Try creating installed app.  rather than a web app.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib


from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. It worked. I was wondering if I can use desktop application type to run my code in an online server? I want to put this code in a server so it can run 24*7 will it work if I use desktop application type?

Comment: The consent screen will open on the server so unless you are remote desktop to the server you may not be able to authorize your code

Comment: if you are only connecting to your own drive account you should probably look at using a service account